# Conversão de propriedades de objetos em numeros

Tags: javascript, conversão-de-tipo

Gostaria de saber como fazer com que os valores de um objeto se tornem números. Li a respeito dos Métodos `valueOf()`, e `toString()`, mas ainda não descobri como utiliza-los para esse fim, minhas tentativas não deram muito resultado. Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 2):

Utilize o método parseInt()

```
var a = parseInt("237");

alert(a);
```

Fonte: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar os métodos `parseInt(<string>)` e `parseFloat(<string>)`.

Você pode ver o uso destas funções [aqui](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp). Mas em essência o que elas fazem é transformar uma string em um número, trocando o tipo de string para int (no caso do `parseInt`) ou para ponto flutuante (no caso do `parseFloat`).

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Objeto original:
var oSrc = {
  "name": "testy McTestFace",
  "age": "21",
  "canDrink": "1",
  "canDrive": "false"
}

//Conversão de propriedades
for (p in oSrc) {                   // Para cada propriedade,
  oSrc[p] = parseInt(oSrc[p])       // Armazene o valor convertido para inteiro
      || oSrc[p];                   // ou mantenha o valor atual.
} 

console.log(oSrc);
```

Resultado:

```
{
  "name": "testy McTestFace",
  "age": 21,                     // Valor convertido
  "canDrink": 1,                 // Valor convertido
  "canDrive": "false"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sem saber o contexto que procuras usar fica meio ampla a pergunta, mas sim, como referiste é possivel em alguns objetos chamar os métodos `.valueOf()` ou `.toString()` e com utilidade.

Esses métodos fazem uma conversão de Tipo, de objeto para string ou de objeto para numero, ás vezes "à bruta" outras com sentido semântico.

Um bom exemplo é um objeto Data, onde podes usar o `.toString()` para converter em texto, e o `.valueOf()` para converter num número, o timestamp.

```
var data = new Date();
data.toString(); // "Fri Jun 03 2016 22:27:57 GMT+0100 (WEST)"
data.valueOf(); // 1464989277351
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, sua pergunta está mesmo meio sem contexto, mas eu creio que entendi qual ponto você quer chegar.

Os métodos `.toString()` e `.valueOf()` são funções especiais que são chamadas implicitamente quando você usa algumas expressões específicas, como conversão direta pra String ou Number.

Como você quer saber como se utilizam elas, então vamos ter que lidar com a construção do objeto em questão.

Exemplo usando `.toString()`:

```
// construtor da "classe" Pessoa
function Pessoa(nome){
    this.nome = nome;

    this.toString = function(){
        return this.nome;
    };
}

var eu = new Pessoa('William');
console.log('Olá, meu nome é '+eu);
// Imprime "Olá, meu nome é William"
console.log(String(eu));
// Imprime "William"
```

Já no caso do método `.valueOf()`, ele referencia explicitamente o valor que você definir, como o seu próprio exemplo, um número:

```
// construtor de um número "especial"
function NumeroEspecial(num){
    this.num = num;

    this.valueOf = function(){
        return this.num;
    };
}

var num = new NumeroEspecial(5);
console.log(num + 1);
// Imprime 6
console.log(Number(num));
// Imprime 5
```

Isso é uma explicação somente pra você saber o processo inicial, existem outros fatores a se considerar antes de usar esses tipos de métodos especiais.

Bom, espero ter ajudado!